# Some sort of bootlog or system info log in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, event-log

I was wondering if there is some sort of "Bootlog" file or anything similar in which I can (at least) see when the computer was booted. So at what date and time that happened.

So basically I need a history of those events. So I can also see when it was booted last week and 2 weeks ago.

Is there a file from which I can get that kind of information in Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at this information in the **Event Viewer**.

Create a **Custom View** with the following parameters:

[image]

The view will include all logged events of when the system was started.